# AWS RDS listen on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a simple AWS RDS instance which I wish to connect to from behind a corporate firewall which blocks all outgoing ports except for 80.

From the configuration, it appears RDS prohibits listening on ports < 1150.

What is the simplest way to get around this? I could create a EC2 instance to act as a proxy but this seems overkill.

Is there an AWS service or configuration I can use to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Create another machine and use it as SSH tunnel. I do it for connecting MongoDB, but the client tool should support to enter SSH tunnel details.

Find in my blog about details on how to create a machine with SSH connection on port 80: http://barisnet.blogspot.com/2016/05/connect-mongodb-using-ssh-tunnel-on.html